# How to update Mongodb documents in Mule?

Tags: mongodb, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to update a document in my Stores collection in Mongodb from Mule using the storeId field in the document.

I've read information on this but the examples show the query as just #[payload].  I just wanted to find out the syntax that should be used in the MongoDB connector so I can update a date field if it is before todays date or null where a storeId = "1234".

How do I set up Mule's MongoDB connector to do this and is their any supporting documentation on how to setup the mongodb operations in the connector?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the link

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mongodb-connector

MongoDB is a cross-platform document-oriented database. Classified as a NoSQL database, MongoDB eschews the traditional table-based relational database structure in favor of JSON-like documents with dynamic schemas (MongoDB calls the format BSON), making the integration of data in certain types of applications easier and faster.

Comment: I cannot see any information regarding how to config the different mongodb operations such as the syntax for the different fields